# Replacing space with &nbsp; causes invisble â character

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am populating a select box with a list of options like this:

```
optionsString = optionsString.replace(/\s/g, '&nbsp;');
```

I am doing this to preserve the spaces between the words. I do not want the DOM to remove additional spaces if I have words like:

```
<option>a b    c</option>
```

If I console log the value of the select box I get:

`a b    c`  instead of `a b c` which is exactly what I want. However, there is a hidden character  â that gets added after b.

When I sent the string to the backend database, the database was not able to find any record belonging to a b    c. When I converted the string to hexadecimal I saw the invisible character. Is there a way to not remove space without adding this special character?

Comment: How are you using `optionsString`? Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that `&nbsp;` creates a **non-breaking space**, not just a space. If you're using the value of the option, it will have non-breaking spaces in it, not just spaces. If you want them to be spaces, you have to replace them with spaces:

```
const value = theSelectBoxOrOptionElement.value.replace(/\u00A0/g, " ");
```

(`\u00A0` is the non-breaking space character that `&nbsp;` creates.)

Note, though, that `\s` will match any whitespace, not just a space, so your `replace` is a lossy operation (all kinds of whitespace are replaced with `&nbsp;`, so we can't know which were which when we want to go back).

Here's an example:

```js
let optionsString = `a b    c`;
optionsString = optionsString.replace(/\s/g, "&nbsp;");

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
    `beforeend`,
    `<select id="the-select">
        <option>${optionsString}</option>
    </select>`
);

const select = document.getElementById(`the-select`);
const rawValue = select.value;
console.log(`rawValue:`, codePoints(rawValue));
const updated = rawValue.replace(/\u00A0/g, " ");
console.log(`updated:`, codePoints(updated));

function codePoints(value) {
    return [...value].map(v => v.codePointAt(0).toString(16).padStart(2, "0")).join(" ");
}
```